# How do I prevent RestAssured from overwriting mocks with real implementations?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jersey, easymock, rest-assured

I'm trying to test a Jersey REST service endpoint with RestAssured while mocking its dependency. I use Spring to autowire the endpoint, and I set a mock dependency before executing the test. However, when RestAssured calls the service, it gets re-autowired again, and my mock is replaced with the real implementation. How do I prevent that?

I'm using Spring Boot, Jersey, EasyMock and RestAssured.

My endpoint class:

```
@Component
@Path("foo")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public class FooEndpoint {

    private FooService service;

    @GET
    @Produces({MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN})
    public String get() {
        return service.getFoo();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setService(FooService service) {
        System.out.println(String.format("<<< Endpoint %s. Setting service %s", this, service));
        this.service = service;
    }

}
```

FooService:

```
@Service
public class FooService {

    public String getFoo() {
        return "real foo";
    }

}
```

Test:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = {Application.class}, webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class FooEndpointIT {

    @LocalServerPort
    private int port;

    @Autowired
    private FooEndpoint target;

    private FooService serviceMock;

    @Test
    public void testGet() {
        RestAssured.port = port;
        String expected = "mock foo";

        serviceMock = EasyMock.strictMock(FooService.class);
        target.setService(serviceMock);

        EasyMock.expect(serviceMock.getFoo()).andReturn(expected);
        EasyMock.replay(serviceMock);
        String actual = RestAssured.get("foo").body().asString();
        System.out.println(actual);
        assertEquals("mock foo", actual); // Fails: expected:<[mock] foo> but was:<[real] foo>
    }

}
```

And in the logs I see this:

> <<< Endpoint com.foo.foo.FooEndpoint@6972c30a. Setting service com.foo.foo.FooService@57a48985
>
> . . . Tomcat initializes and starts . . .
>
> <<< Endpoint com.foo.foo.FooEndpoint@6972c30a. Setting service EasyMock for class com.foo.foo.FooService
>   <<< Endpoint com.foo.foo.FooEndpoint@6972c30a. Setting service com.foo.foo.FooService@57a48985
>   real foo

How do I prevent the FooEndpoint from being re-autowired after I set my mock?